# Unable to Control button image changes of cells on click

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to create a simple application in which each cell in a table view has a heart button. If I click on the heart button, it should get filled. Unfortunately, each time I click it, other hearts in other cells also become filled. I've found this is due to cell recycling. I have tried a lot of different things to try and solve this but am not sure what is the exact process. Here is the code for the app:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:heartcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("heart") as! heartcell

    cell.heartButton.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.heartButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "heartsUnfillled"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.heartButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "heartsFilled"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

    cell.heartButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    return cell
}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    let ip = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)
    let cell = someTB.cellForRowAtIndexPath(ip) as! heartcell
    cell.heartButton.selected = !cell.heartButton.selected

}
```

Clearly, the cells are getting recycled and this isn't working. I've tried storing the cells in an array, storing their respective indexes in an array, but regardless I still get the same issue where I can't control the hearts that are getting filled. Does anybody know how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you try with this function: didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: Since cells are reused, you can't rely on the cell object to store any state data.  You need to track the selection state in some other property, such as an NSIndexSet and then use that in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

Comment: How would I do that exactly, like store the rows of the selected cells in a set?

Answer (score 0):

You should declare a set:

```
var filledHeartSet = Set<NSIndexPath>()
```

And use it in your code like this:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell:heartcell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("heart") as! heartcell

    cell.heartButton.tag = indexPath.row

    cell.heartButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "heartsUnfillled"), forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    cell.heartButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "heartsFilled"), forState: UIControlState.Selected)

    cell.heartButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonClicked:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    // set current state for heart button
    cell.heartButton.selected = filledHeartSet.contains(indexPath)

    return cell
}

func buttonClicked(sender:UIButton)
{
    let ip = NSIndexPath(forRow: sender.tag, inSection: 0)

    // only store filled heart indexPath
    if filledHeartSet.contains(ip) {
        filledHeartSet.remove(ip)
    } else {
        filledHeartSet.insert(ip)
    }

    let cell = someTB.cellForRowAtIndexPath(ip) as! heartcell
    cell.heartButton.selected = !cell.heartButton.selected
}
```